# Как настроить словарь в aspell?

Tags: bash

С помощью aspell проверяю консольно файлы на наличие опечаток.

```
aspell --encoding=cp1251 -H -c <file>
```

Использую русский словарь, однако при этом все английские слова отмечаются как ошибки. Как можно этого избежать? Вариант с полным игнором всех английских слов меня полностью устроит. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

по вот [этому совету](https://superuser.com/a/243642/454489) можно использовать список игнорируемых слов.

получить список можно, например, из пакетов `wamerican`/`wbritish`/`wcanadian`.